# PL/SQL - Access the Cursor Data Dynamically

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have used two cursors
1) c_emp cursor has table data.
2) c_column_names cursor has columns from the table.
I want to fetch data from c_emp cursor for all columns using c_column_names cursor dynamically.

I have tried to use the following code but it's not working:

```
create or replace procedure sp_read_data(in_tb_nm varchar2) as
cursor c_emp is select * from test_table;
begin    
    open c_column_names for select column_name from all_tab_columns where table_name = 'TEST_TABLE';      
    for emp_row in c_emp
    loop    
      loop
          fetch c_column_names into lc_record;
          exit when c_column_names %notfound;                
          lc_col_nm := 'emp_row.'||lc_record;
          v_dtl := v_dtl || rpad (lc_col_nm, 20, ' ');
      end loop;     
    end loop;      
end sp_read_data;
```

Is there a way to access the cursor data dynamically?

Comment: Not clear what you try to achieve. What is the purpose of parameter `in_tb_nm`? Where did you declare `lc_record`? Maybe show us how the static SQL would look like.

Comment: What was the need of 2 loops here?. Also, let us know what is your final expected result. There could be far easier methods to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

I *think* that you're, kind of, reinventing the wheel. Why not using a REF CURSOR?

```
SQL> create or replace function sp_read_data (in_tb_nm in varchar2)
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    cur_r sys_refcursor;
  5  begin
  6    open cur_r for 'select * from ' || in_tb_nm;
  7    return cur_r;
  8  end;
  9  /

Function created.

SQL> select sp_read_data('departments') from dual;
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1
           10 Administration                        200        1700
           20 Marketing                             201        1800
           30 Purchasing                            114        1700
           40 Human Resources                       203        2400
           50 Shipping                              121        1500
           60 IT                                    103        1400
           <snip>
```